# Chrome issuing malware warning when visiting SF question

Tags: support, specific-question

When I visit [this SF question](https://serverfault.com/questions/79485/windows-2008-winsxs-directory-growing-uncontrollably-blocking-server), Chrome warns me of malware because of several (perfectly innocent) images from `imgurl.Filetac.com` a user embedded in it:

[image]

I assume this is sorted now that it's no longer possible to hotlink external images in SF questions, but to let you know in case this is somehow relevant.

Comment: It is still possible to hotlink external images, you just have to write the Markdown yourself rather than using the button for it.

Comment: Odd, I don't receive that error on v6.0.472.55 for Windows.  What are you security settings at?

Comment: @gWaldo I think that's because @splattne replaced them (see his answer below)

Answer (score 1):

I'm note sure about answers, but profiles allow adding external images on all stack-exchange sites.. oh & here too ==> [image]

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record: I've replaced the images on [Joseph Kern's answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/79485/windows-2008-winsxs-directory-growing-uncontrollably-blocking-server/84461#84461) with imgur.com URLs.

I think - even if it's not justified - no SF page should ever trigger a browser's malware warning.

Comment: Yup, I agree with that.